# I want to replace HTML tag with another JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, class, tags, queryselector

[image]

In JavaScript, I would like to simply change the

`<section class="row">` to `<div class="row">`

Preferably in the least amount of code as possible to keep it simple :) I was using `document.querySelector` but that is as far as I got. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score -1):

You could try

```js
const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
const oldSection = document.querySelector('section.row');
newDiv.innerHTML = oldSection.innerHTML;
newDiv.className = 'row';
oldSection.replaceWith(newDiv);
```